# Error parsing query in SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-ce

I am running my query using WebMatrix, I think it is correct, however I am getting an error.

My query is as follows :

```
   var result = db.Query(
                @"SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, e.event_start, e.event_end, e.group_id, e.recurring
                FROM   event e
                JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
                WHERE  e.recurring = 0
                AND    m.UserID = @0
                AND    e.event_start >= @1
                AND    e.event_end <= @2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_start), DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_end), e.group_id, e.recurring
                FROM   event e
               JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
               CROSS JOIN 
                ( SELECT  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks
                  FROM SYS.OBJECTS
                ) AS w
                WHERE  e.recurring = 1
                AND    m.user_id = 4;
                AND    e.event_start >= @4
                AND    e.event_end <= @5", userID, start, end, userID, start, end
            );
```

The error is :

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an
>   error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 10,Token line offset =
>   38,Token in error = OVER ]    at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)    at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()

I'm holding query in a .cs file. I'm told I should create a stored procedure since SQL Server compact may not support the OVER function, is this correct? How can I create a stored procedure for this query?

Comment: Simon, you seem to be coming across a lot of cases where you want to use SQL Server syntax in SQL Server Compact, and the syntax is not 100% compatible. Have you considered using Express or the new LocalDb in SQL Server 2012? Watch this presentation before you answer: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/SQL11UPD03-REC-07

Comment: Added compact edition to the tags... I assume CE doesn't support `row_number` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After FROM, you can list multiple tables separated by comma's, and the result will be a CROSS JOIN of all those tables.

But you can't use the comma syntax after a JOIN.  Instead, write out the CROSS JOIN:

```
JOIN   Membership m 
ON     m.GroupID = e.group_id
CROSS JOIN 
       (
       SELECT  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks
       FROM SYS.OBJECTS
       ) AS w
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. What is the best/easiest way that I can run this query on my server? At the moment it is completely made using WebMatrix/SQL Server CE. I'm worried its going to take a huge amount of work to migrate everything over and change my code! :(

Comment: If you're looking for a list of week numbers, create a table and filling it with number 1 to 53 should do the trick?

Comment: I have migrated to SQL Server now, and I am getting the error ">Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: I have updated my code above to show what I am currently running.

Comment: Might be the semicolon here: `m.user_id = 4;`  SQL Server interprets a semicoln as end of statement.

Comment: many thanks for the response. I have fixed that and posted a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665051/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-webmatrix-data-dynamicrecord-to-a-known-manag any idea what could be the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems ROW_NUMBER and other windowed functions are not supported by Sql Server CE 4.0 :(

Comment: :( Is there any way for me to get around this?

Comment: You use row_number to generate sequence of numbers - probably you need to have generated it in static table. It is not elegant solution but it is better than nothing I think.