# No mapping exists from object type WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, compiler-errors

I am very confused with the error my SQL server is returning - what would be causing this?

The C# code I am running is :

```
List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
        var db = Database.Open("myDatabase");
        string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("username").Value;
        var listOfGroups = db.Query("SELECT GroupID FROM Membership WHERE UserID = (SELECT UserID from Users WHERE Username = @0 )",  username);

        foreach(var groupID in listOfGroups)
            {
                var result = db.Query(
                    @"SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, e.event_start, e.event_end, e.group_id, e.recurring
                    FROM   event e
                    JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
                    WHERE  e.recurring = 0
                    AND    m.GroupID = @0
                    AND    e.event_start >= @1
                    AND    e.event_end <= @2
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_start), DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_end), e.group_id, e.recurring
                    FROM   event e
                JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
                CROSS JOIN 
                    ( SELECT  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks
                    FROM SYS.OBJECTS
                    ) AS w
                    WHERE  e.recurring = 1
                    AND    m.GroupID = $3
                    AND    e.event_start >= @4
                    AND    e.event_end <= @5", groupID, start, end, groupID, start, end
                );
                foreach(var record in result)
                    {
                            CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent();
                            cevent.id = record.event_id;
                            cevent.title = record.title;
                            cevent.description = record.description;
                            cevent.start = record.event_start;
                            cevent.end = record.event_end;
                            cevent.recurring = record.recurring;
                            events.Add(cevent);
                    }
            }
        return events;
}
```

And the error:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from
>   object type WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to a known managed provider
>   native type.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it ?

What I wish to do is return all events where recurring = 0, and any events where recurring =1 I want to be returned for their week and the 52 weeks thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your issue is with your `groupID` input parameter.

```
var listOfGroups = db.Query("SELECT GroupID FROM Membership WHERE UserID = (SELECT UserID from Users WHERE Username = @0 )",  username);
```

Your `listOfGroups` is coming back as a collection of the `WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord` objects.  You seem to want just the `int` value, as you get `groupID` in the `foreach(var groupID in listOfGroups)` statement.

Try instead replacing the last line:

```
AND    e.event_end <= @5", groupID, start, end, groupID, start, end
```

with:

```
AND    e.event_end <= @5", (int)groupID.GroupID, start, end, (int)groupID.GroupID, start, end
```

This should pull the value from the first (and only) column of each dynamic query result, that value being the int group ID that you are after.

**EDIT:** Corrected value call syntax of DynamicRecord query result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, however this code actually returns the error : "Invalid column name "Item."

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to WebMatrix. I corrected the syntax -- you can just call GroupID directly as a property from the result from the dynamic query.

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, you might want to rename `groupID` from the local parameter declared in the foreach to something like row or the like, to clarify that each object is a result from the dynamic query, and not actually directly the ID itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. This has fixed my error, however the SQL query still returns the wrong value! I have posted another question here in the hope of finding an answer to that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674005/complicated-sql-server-query thank you very much for the help!