# Complicated SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to write an SQL (Server) query which will return all events on a current day, and for all events where the column `recurring`= 1, I want it to return this event on the day it is being held and for the subsequent 52 weeks following the event.

My tables are structured as followed :

```
Event
{
    event_id (PK)
    title,
    description,
    event_start DATETIME,
    event_end DATETIME,
    group_id,
    recurring
}

Users
{
    UserID (PK)
    Username
}

Groups
{
    GroupID (PK)
    GroupName
}

Membership
{
    UserID (FK)
    GroupID (FK)
}
```

The code I have thus far is as follows :

```
     var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
    string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("mpUsername").Value;
    var listOfGroups = db.Query("SELECT GroupID FROM Membership WHERE UserID = (SELECT UserID from Users WHERE Username = @0 )",  username);
    foreach(var groupID in listOfGroups)
        {
            int newGroupID = groupID.GroupID;
            var result = db.Query(
                @"SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, e.event_start, e.event_end, e.group_id, e.recurring
                FROM   event e
                JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
                WHERE  e.recurring = 0
                AND    m.GroupID = @0
                AND    e.event_start >= @1
                AND    e.event_end <= @2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT e.event_id, e.title, e.description, DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_start), DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_end), e.group_id, e.recurring
                FROM   event e
            JOIN   Membership m ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
            CROSS JOIN 
                ( SELECT  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks
                FROM SYS.OBJECTS
                ) AS w
                WHERE  e.recurring = 1
                AND    m.GroupID = @3
                AND DATEADD(WEEK, w.Weeks, e.event_start) >= @4 
                AND DATEADD(WEEK, w.Weeks, e.event_end) <= @5", newGroupID, start, end, newGroupID, start, end
            );
```

This results in when one queries for the date of the event stored in the database, this event and 52 weeks of events are returned. When one queries for the event the week after this one, nothing is returned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No mapping exists from object type WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to a known managed provider native type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665051/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-webmatrix-data-dynamicrecord-to-a-known-manag)

Comment: The answer in your other question pointed you in the direction of your error... it has nothing to do with your SQL - instead, you're trying to pass in `groupID`, which is a `DynamicRecord`, to `db.Query`.  You would need to get the value from the previous result set, and convert it to an int.  Or, I'd suggest re-writing this code, since I see no reason why you would use the `foreach` instead of doing an additional join in your main query...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson, thank you for the response. I am trying to do this, but as you can tell I am struggling as a beginner with SQL Server and C#. Would you mind suggesting an alternative query I could write using the join you suggested, as I would not have nearly the amount of skill required to write such a piece of code?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson, I'm really unsure how a join would even work in this case, since in the Groups table, there can be multiple instances of the same UserID!

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I have edited my code above so that there is no error with the groupID in C#. The query returns OK, but there are no results even though I have added them in to my table.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson, I've just had something of a realization for why it is not returning properly. One the date a recurring event is added, it is returning all 52 weeks, however on the next week it is not being added at all. This is because of the lines  AND    e.event_start >= @4
            AND    e.event_end <= @5" at the end of the query. Delete these and it returns all recurring entries all of the time. Is it possible to compare the generated dates from the select statements rather than event_start and event_end? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to alter the following 2 lines

```
AND    e.event_start >= @4
AND    e.event_end <= @5"
```

to

```
AND    DATEADD(WEEK, w.Weeks, e.event_start) >= @4
AND    DATEADD(WEEK, w.Weeks, e.event_end) <= @5"
```

However, I'd advise putting all this SQL into a stored procedure, SQL-Server will cache the execution plans and it will result in (slightly) better performance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetEvents @UserName VARCHAR(50), @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
-- DEFINE A CTE TO GET ALL GROUPS ASSOCIATED WITH THE CURRENT USER
;WITH Groups AS 
(   SELECT  GroupID 
    FROM    Membership  m
            INNER JOIN Users u
                ON m.UserID = u.UserID
    WHERE   Username = @UserName
    GROUP BY GroupID
),
-- DEFINE A CTE TO GET ALL EVENTS FOR THE GROUPS DEFINED ABOVE
AllEvents AS
(   SELECT  e.*
    FROM    event e
            INNER JOIN Groups m 
                ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  e.event_id, e.title, e.description, DATEADD(WEEK, w.weeks, e.event_start), DATEADD(WEEK, w.weeks, e.event_end), e.group_id, e.recurring
    FROM    event e
            INNER JOIN Groups m 
                ON m.GroupID = e.group_id
            CROSS JOIN 
            (   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks
                FROM    SYS.OBJECTS
            ) AS w
    WHERE  e.recurring = 1
)   
-- GET ALL EVENTS WHERE THE EVENTS FALL IN THE PERIOD DEFINED
SELECT  *
FROM    AllEvents
WHERE   Event_Start >= @StartDate
AND     Event_End <= @EndDate

END
```

Then you can call this with

```
var result = db.Query("EXEC dbo.GetEvents @0, @1, @2", username, start, end);
```

This elimates the need to iterate over groups in your code behind. If this is actually a requirement then you could modify the stored procedure to take @GroupID as a parameter, and change the select statements/where clauses as necessary.

I have assumed knowledge of [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). They are not required to make the query work, they just make things slightly more legible in my opinion. I can rewrite this without them if required.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer - it is really helpful to me as a beginner. Thank you. I am trying to edit my code simply so that it will work first (the first, simpler solution you provided). I am still having a problem though, it is currently not returning any events. I have edited my code above to show what I am currently running. Any ideas, before I set about making the other changes you suggested ? :)

Comment: @GarethdD Also, should that be INNER JOIN Groups m  
                ON m.GroupID = e.group_id? I think? I am completely guessing, since thats how I got it to compile :)

Comment: and now I have it compiling, with one tiny error - the event is being returned for every date...except the date it is added!

Comment: @SimonKiely Yes, sorry it should be m.GroupID not e.GroupID. I have updated my answer, I've also corrected the issue of the 1st recurring event not being returned.

Comment: Amazing. I've been working on this code for weeks and you've done it in a few hours. Incredible. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would check my parameters one at a time against some trivial SQL, just to rule them out as possible culprits. Something like this:

```
var result = db.Query("select r=cast(@0 as varchar(80))",username);
var result = db.Query("select r=cast(@0 as int)",newGroupID);
var result = db.Query("select r=cast(@0 as datetime)",start);
var result = db.Query("select r=cast(@0 as datetime)",end);
```

Comment: This was an error, however I have corrected it and my code will still not work unfortunately!

Comment: Is it possible debug-print the SQL and run in SSMS?

Comment: Does the @ belong in front of the second query? I noticed it's not in front of the first. `@"SELECT`

Comment: Yes, it does, that just shows that it is a multi-line query, I believe!

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I have edited my code somewhat following your advice and now I have a new error. When one queries for the date of the event stored in the database, this event and 52 weeks of events are returned. When one queries for the event the week after this one, nothing is returned. Is there any way I can check the parameters 'start' and 'end against the generated datetimes?

Comment: Your date clauses could look like `DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_start) >= @4 and DATEADD(week, w.weeks, e.event_end) <= @5`

Comment: I have edited the code to run this solution and it returns no results! (however there are values stored in the database)